# Restore feature in In-App Purchase in iphone/ipad application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, in-app-purchase

I have integrated in-app purchases in my application and tested on my device. It's working properly.
But when I upload binary on iTunes store Apple reject my application due to this reason:

```
"We found that your app offers In-App Purchase/s that can be restored but it does not    
include a "Restore" feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased In-App     
Purchase/s."
```

I couldn't understand what is the actual problem.

Comment: Have you implemented - (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction in your code?

Comment: @NuzhatZari:yes i have integrate this method in my code.
Code - 
[self recordTransaction:transaction];
   [self provideContent:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
   
   [self finishMyTransaction:transaction];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761556/restore-already-bought-in-app-purchases-on-iphone#

Comment: follow this will link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975312/no-restore-button-for-in-app-purchase-causes-rejection

hope it'll help you.

Comment: Visit this link:- http://www.spaceotechnologies.com/blog/case-study-iphone-app-rejection-due-missing-restore-button-in-app-purchase/

Answer (score 3):

Are you using MKStoreKit by chance? I am, and received the same rejection message.

To solve the issue, I added a button that says "Restore In-App Purchases", and calls `restorePreviousTransactionsOnComplete:onError:` which will allow the user to restore any previously purchased IAPs.