# No restore button for in app purchase causes rejection

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am implementing an application using in app purchase with non-consumables items, it was rejected by apple and the reason is:

> We found that your app offers In-App Purchase/s that can be restored but it does not include a "Restore" feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased In-App Purchase/s.
>
> To restore previously purchased In-App Purchase products, it would be appropriate to provide a "Restore" button and initiate the restore process when the "Restore" button is tapped.
>
> For more information about restoring transactions and verifying store receipts, please refer to the

and there is no link to refer to, I have already implemented the:

`- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions`

with
`SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` case.

but I didnt implement:

```
`restoreCompletedTransactions`  or `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`
```

are these methods necessary for the in app purchase to be approved, or what is the exact problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the following to restore the products ID's that user did purchased from your app

```
- (void) checkPurchasedItems
{
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}// Call This Function

//Then this delegate Function Will be fired
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
  purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
  for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
  {
      NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
      [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
  }

}
```

the purchasedItemIDs will contain all the product IDs that the user purchased it .. you could put a button to call this function when it finished you show all these products to enable the user to download it again.

Comment: is this a necessary feature, I didnt see this option on any application before

Comment: actually yes it is .. there is a lot of apps implement this option , I used it in all my applications. and based on apple report you can see they required it in case you are using in app purchase.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761556/restore-already-bought-in-app-purchases-on-iphone#

Comment: Thanks it solves my problem. For others, if you don't provide restore feature, Apple will reject your application. This is their new policy.

Comment: This is as par Apple's documentation for this function "This method is called after all restorable transactions have been processed by the payment queue. Your application is not required to do anything in this method.". Check out documentation from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you very much, i have used same code and now apple approved my app, thanks again for really wondering help.

Comment: @Malek_Jundi is this still applicable? if the purchases is a 'remove-ads' feature, when would i call the method to update screens & userdefaults to ignore ads in the future? in the finished delegate method after i checked the ID of the restored transactions?