# In-App Purchase Restore

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am adding a Restore Previous Purchases button to my iPhone app, next to the Purchase button (Non-Consumable IAP Product). When the Restore button is pressed the app calls [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions], which seems to be working in the sense that something happens and a dialog appears, however I wanted to check that this dialog is indeed the one that is intended to appear. Because the dialog that appears when I press Restore looks exactly like the one that appears when I click Purchase ("Do you want to buy ..."). Then after I click Buy and enter my password, another dialog appears saying "You have already bought this. Press OK to download for free" or something like that.

My question: Is this the intended behavior for restoring In-App Purchases? Should not the dialog rather say something like "Do you wish to restore purchased items?"

---

EDIT: I have come up with a theory; is it possible that the behavior described above only happens when using test accounts against App Store? So that the App Store simply does not remember purchases for test users?

Comment: I'm in the same boat you are in.  It would suck if your test user account could not test this.  I wanted to automatically call restoreCompletedTransactions but the user is prompted for a password which would scare then at startup.  Because my app still restores the purchase like you discribe above, I asked the apple test center if I could just have a "buy/restore" button.  That way the user would know that their in-app purchase could be restored if they had to re-install the app.

Comment: has apple answered your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975312/no-restore-button-for-in-app-purchase-causes-rejection

Answer (score 0):

That is the intended behavior for restore dialog¨¨ In-App purchases, you won't get a dialog saying "do you wish to restore...."

You can label your button as Restore

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your restore button is actually calling `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`?

I have no problem with test users. And @Tapman answer is not correct, as it only asks for your password and does NOT show the "Do you want to load this for free" dialog.