# Implementing server side In-App purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, video, in-app-purchase

According to my requirement, I have to implement in-app purchase functionality for  purchasing individual video.These videos we are getting from our server on in run-time by using REST apis.

We have implemented the "non-consumable type of purchase" for our in-app purchase but only when we have the categories based product listed in In-App store.

Our concern is, is there any way by which we can get the bundle identifier for each individual video in our app and implement as we are getting all the product from our own server and each product has different price.

Please guide me on Server side in-app purchase implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I worked on an app like yours, I will recommend you to make categories of videos and apply Non-Consumable in-App Purchases on a particular category, if the user buys a category, all videos of that category will be unlocked. And I spent a lot of time in implementing IAP, but one tutorial helped me out successfully. Follow it, it also has code to how to restore already completed transactions. Here is the link. [IAP Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial)

i Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have also implement consumable in-app purchase and hide the purchase video from purchase section after purchasing a video by hitting a web service but apple reject my application for the reason "invalid in-app purchase type".

Comment: Sorry ,We can not categorise videos because we want to implement in-app purchase functionality for indivisible video purchase.(we are using same price for all indivisible video)

Comment: Try Non-consumable  , and please paste full reason of rejection sent by apple

Comment: for restore button se it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975312/no-restore-button-for-in-app-purchase-causes-rejection?rq=1

Comment: App rejection reason is this:  11.7: Apps that use IAP to purchase items must assign the correct Purchasability type

Comment: You have used Consumable IAP , change the type to Non-Consumable Type.it will work perfectly.