# iOS6 - In app purchase with download from Apple server

Tags: ios, download, in-app-purchase

I'm able to successfully make the inapp purchase and download the content from Apple server and use it. 
My In app purchase content is non-consumable. And so I'm providing "Restore" button in my app
Now when user presses "Restore" button, I'm calling the method:

```
restoreCompletedTransactions
```

But here, I'm not getting the call to delegate method:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

So that I can identify the transaction object and start downloading the content again from apple server. Can some one help me in writing "restore" option?

As per apple, it says:

*// Asynchronous.  Will add completed transactions for the current user back to the queue to be re-completed.  User will be asked to authenticate.  Observers will receive 0 or more -paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:, followed by either -paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished: on success or -paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError: on failure.  In the case of partial success, some transactions may still be delivered.*

But for me, I'm not getting the call "paymentQueue:updatedTransactions" at all. I'm just getting the call "paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not observe transaction queue. Make sure you have

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

somewhere before you call restoreCompletedTransactions method

Comment: After restore, I'm getting call back: - (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue but how to get the transaction object and get the content to download?

Comment: This is strange. paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: method should be called. Could it be possible that this method was invoked earlier but you did not call [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction] after it? If this is the case, removing app from the device and trying to restore product again with the same test user should do it.

Comment: I tried that. I removed the app and trying to restore the product with same test user.... still I am not getting call to "updatedTransactions".