# How to keep tracking of purchase item in in-app purchase

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase, in-app

I have knowledge about in-app purchase, but stuck in implementing in app purchase in my case.
I have a list of videos coming from server when I click on any video I can download it in two formats, one low resolution and other is high resolution after in-app purchase. I have created two product identifier in itunes and have no any problem in implementing. But how will I keep track of the video and resolution I have purchased and also how will I use restore to get that product again if I purchased it once. Any advise will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Restore in-App purchase :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761556/restore-already-bought-in-app-purchases-on-iphone

Comment: @Rushabh if on restore we can get the purchased product identifier right?.BUt in my senarion i have many files i have purchased with same identifier how will get this info .like i have two identifiers high and low and if i have purchased three different videos in high resolution the i will use the same product identifier as i have two identifiers one for low resolution one for high